# How to use the SpringBoot's context for testing by JerseyTest

Tags: java, rest, testing, spring-boot, jersey

I have some ***@Component*** and ***@Resource*** in my ***SpringBoot*** application.
I have the right JDBC datasource, and also I have some REST services, by Jersey.
I want to test one of the services, but it will fail, it says:

> Injection of autowired dependencies failed

But it does not use any component.

This is a simple test for testing db, and **it is working**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class CommonRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    public void testDatabaseChangeLogsSize() {
        int resultSize = myRepository.getTableRowSize(MyTable.TABLE_NAME);
        System.out.println("MyTable result list size: "+resultSize);
        assertTrue("MyTable table should has at least one row!", resultSize>0);
    }

}
```

But this REST tester **is not working**:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class SampleResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyApplication.class);
        return new ResourceConfig(SampleResource.class).property("contextConfig", context);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSampleGet() throws Exception {
        long id = 1;
        String name = "name";
        SampleDomainModel sampleDomainModel = new SampleDomainModel();
        sampleDomainModel.setId(id);
        sampleDomainModel.setName(name);
        Response response = target("/sampleresource/samplepath/" + id).queryParam(name).request().get(Response.class);
        SampleDomainModel responseSampleDomainModel = response.readEntity(SampleDomainModel.class);
        assertEquals(sampleDomainModel.getId(), responseSampleDomainModel.getId());
    }

}
```

As you see, it must override the ***configure()*** method from ***JerseyTest***.
I think the problam is, that the ***AnnotationConfigApplicationContext*** cannot load anything maybe (?).
The ***@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)*** annotation loads the context, but the ***new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyApplication.class)*** code maybe do the failure, it does not have the full context.

If I replace the code with mocking, it works (but it is not a nice way):

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
    ApplicationContext mockContext = Mockito.mock(ApplicationContext.class);
    return new ResourceConfig(SampleResource.class).property("contextConfig", mockContext);
}
```

The fail message is:

```
2016-05-13 13:25:39.617  WARN 9832 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepositoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.repository.impl.myRepositoryImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.422 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.ws.server.SampleResourceTest
testSampleGetWithCorrectParameters(com.ws.server.SampleResourceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.015 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myRepositoryImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.repository.impl.MyRepositoryImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121)
```

How to use the SpringBoot context for this jersey test?

Answer (score 4):

SImply put, you can't use both Spring's TestContext and Jersey Test Framework together. They will operate on two different `ApplicationContext`s. Even if you try to inject the `ApplicationContext` (created be the TestContext) into the test class and pass it to the `ResourceConfig` in the `configure` method, it's too late, as the injection doesn't occur until *after* construction, but the `configure method is called *during* contruction.

Forget `JerseyTest` and just use [`@WebIntegrationTest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/WebIntegrationTest.html). See [the sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.5.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey/src/test/java/sample/jersey/SampleJerseyApplicationTests.java) from the spring boot project.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(SampleJerseyApplication.class)
@WebIntegrationTest(randomPort = true)
public class SampleJerseyApplicationTests {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    private int port;
```

In a Jersey/Boot environment, Jersey needs to run in a web app environment, and that's what the `@WebIntegrationTest` does.

For the client, instead of just calling `target` on the `JerseyTest`, you will just need to create the client

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:" + this.port);

Response response = target.path("/sampleresource/samplepath/" + id).request().get();
```